# Using Bootstrap 3 alpha, Accordion isnt opening only on Edge. Works fine on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: c#, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Was wondering if you guys had any idea why the class collapse or even the whole accordion is not working only on IE / Edge. Here's the code

```
 <td class="record-id">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link accord-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-targets=".series-@item.RecordSeriesId"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button><a style="color:#374767; text-decoration:none;" >@item.Id.ToString()</a>
 </td>

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accord-button').click(function() {
        var icon = $(this).find('.fa');
        var targets = $($(this).attr('data-targets'));
        if(icon.hasClass("fa-plus")) {
            icon.removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
            targets.removeClass('collapse');
        }else {
            icon.removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
            targets.addClass('collapse');
        }
    });
  function screenListener(e) {
  if (e.matches) {
    $('#dashboard-tabs-collapse').addClass('collapse');
  } else {
    $('#dashboard-tabs-collapse').removeClass('collapse');
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't included your HTML that the jQuery is working on, so we can't help with errors that we can't see! Please include the relevant code in a [minimal, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see the problem in action and be able to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten My apologies. I've attached a small snippet of the html we are using. It's being used in a table hence the <tr> and <td>

Comment: We still can't reproduce the problem because your question doesn't include all the required code. For example, what are `@item.Id.ToString()`, where are the targets, where does the `screenListener` function come in? If we can't see the problem and the code that's causing it, we can't help to fix it!